# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Please increase memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, javadoc, java-11

I have been working on JDK11 Migration, when i build my package , javadoc throwing the following error.

```
> -standard-javadoc:
[ht:javadoc] Generating Javadoc
[ht:javadoc] Javadoc execution
[ht:javadoc] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048M
[ht:javadoc] 1 error
[ht:javadoc] javadoc: error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Please increase memory.
[ht:javadoc] For example, on the JDK Classic or HotSpot VMs, add the option -J-Xmx
[ht:javadoc] such as -J-Xmx32m.
```

I have tried following solutions
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Xmx2048M -> does not work
added jvmarg in build.xml

```
 <property name="default-jvm-args" value="
    -Xmx8G
    -Xms8G
    />
```

I guess i am facing similar issue mentioned in this post , but i am not sure how to root cause the problem
[Out of memory error in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618450/out-of-memory-error-in-ant)

Comment: Did you try the syntax suggested in the error message, i.e. `-J-Xmx2048M`?

Comment: <property name="javadoc.maxmemory" value="256m"/>
this i have added in my  javadoc.xml file and it worked.